# Quasi-reflexive spaces which are not isometric to dual spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

My question may sound weird and I have no deep motivation behind it other than curiosity.

As is well-known, quasi-reflexive spaces have the Radon-Nikodym property hence their balls have lots of extreme points (they even have the so-called Krein-Milman property). However, can one give me an example of a quasi-reflexive space which is not *isometric* to a dual space? Of course, every quasireflexive space is isomorphic to a dual space.

I suspect that a clever renorming of the James space should do the job.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027019

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every non-reflexive Banach space can be equivalently renormed so as not to be isometrically isomorphic to a dual space.
$$
$$
Davis, William J.; Johnson, William B.
A renorming of nonreflexive Banach spaces. 
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 37 (1973), 486–488.

Comment: @Prawem_Kaduka, well, he had the paper ready since 1973! :-)